# Is there a easy and useful error handling algorithm for bottom-up based parser?

Tags: compiler, parsing, error-handling

My English skill is poor because I'm not a native English speaker.
Please understand.

I wonder that there is a error handling algorithm easy and useful in LR parser.
LR Parser is bottom up based so it make difficult on error handling.

For example let's assume there is a grammar like below.

[image]

Here, If user is typed "while (" then top-down based parser knows it is the While Statement because top-down as below.

[image]

So top-down based parser can know what token is missed because it knows whole structure of While Statement.

But bottom-up based parser doesn't know what token is missed because it doesn't know whole structure before be reduce.

For example if user is typed "while (" on bottom-up based parser, it would recognizes only 'while' and '(' token as below. This means it doesn't know what token is missed or what token has to come on bottom-up based parser because it doesn't know whole structure before do reduce.

[image]

For this reason, the error handling on bottom-up based parser more difficult than top-down.

So I wonder something as below.

1. Is there an error handling algorithm that can use like top-down error handling algorithm on bottom-up based parser?
2. If it is not exist, is there a easy and useful error handling algorithm for bottom-up based parser?
3. What is an typical error handling algorithm that used on bottom-up parser?

Thanks for reading.